# unable to insert data in database using json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

i want to insert my data using json.
here is my code

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Register</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MyJs.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name : </td>
                <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password : </td>
                <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>                
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" /><br />
                    <div id="loadingPanel" style="color:green; font-weight:bold;display:none;">Data Saving...</div>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Visible="false" Text="chk"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my jquery code is .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Button1').on('click', function () {
        var uname = $('#TextBox1').val();
        var upass = $('#TextBox2').val();
        $('#loadingPanel').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/SaveData",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "name": uname,
                "pass": upass
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d == "success") {
                    alert("Data saved successfully");                    
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        }).done(function () {
            // here hide loading panel as function complete
            $('#loadingPanel').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

my code behind code is

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string SaveData(string name,string pass)
    {
        string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
        string status = string.Empty;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Login values ('"+name+"','"+pass+"')",con);
        int flag = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (flag > 0)
        {

            status = "success";
        }

        return status;
    }
```

but when i click on submit button it doesn't inserting data. it simply refreshes the page. and also it is not showing any error.

Comment: have you enabled webmethod functionality in scriptmanager? `<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />` Because then you can simply call `PageMethods.SaveData($('#TextBox1').val(), $('#TextBox2').val());`

Comment: i have written that , but the same result .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your button code

```
 <input type="button" id="Button1" value="sub" />
```

and here is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Button1').on('click', function () {
        var uname = $('#TextBox1').val();
        var upass = $('#TextBox2').val();
        call(uname, upass);

    });
});

function call(uname, upass) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/SaveData",
        data: "{name : '" + uname + "', pass: '" + upass + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",       
        success: function (v) {
            alert("OK");
        },
        error: function (v) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have start method name as capital character

`$.Ajax({...`

You should replace it with

`$.ajax({...`

and return false from the click event so as to prevent from page postback.

Comment: i have replaced Ajax with ajax. but didn't get your second statement . can you explain me please

Comment: does it postback the page now? did you return false from the click event?? debug and check the console

Comment: yes it is postback , but after clicking on submit button, a popup is open "The page at localhost:2309 says". after clicking on Ok , it is getting post back

Answer (score 0):

Don´t use an asp:button when you don´t need its server side event anyway. Just use a simple html button or input type button for your onclick event.

If you decide to use a html button keep in mind, that older IE Version need also a type of button assigned. If you don't do that older versionf of IE will always submit the form.

```
<button type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="whatever" />
```